# [CMake]: How to match Unicode characters in REGEX command?

Tags: regex, cmake

is it possible in CMake to write down a `string(REGEX MATCHALL "^[xxx]*")` pattern such that it will match an unicode string? For example, "abcčřž" etc. What should the 'xxx' sequence look like?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want this:

```
^\p{L}+$
```

You might want to take a look [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html).